# How to convert the html tag string to a word document using PHPWord?

Tags: php, html, phpword

I have a HTML string and I want to print in the word document in same format and style as in the HTML. I am using the [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/)

When I give my HTML string say:

`$htmlval ="<h6><div style="text-align: center;"><b style=\\"font-size: x-large;\\">OFFER LETTER</b></div><font size=\\"3\\"><div style="text-align: center;"><span style=\\"font-size: medium;\\">(This goes as an email copy)</span></div>";`

this is the HTML tags with break and div.

to:

```
$section->addText($htmlval);
```

it prints all HTML tag but I want the content with the format specified in the HTML.

Answer (score 22):

In limited way its possible, but just only for basic html tags.

```
<p>,<h1>,<h2>,<h3>,<h4>,<h5>,<h6>,<strong>,
<em>,<sup>,<sub>,<table>,<tr>,<td>,<ul>,<ol>,<li>
```

Its also not work well in more complicated cases (for example rowspan/colspan in tables)

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $html);
```

Please check samples on : [PHPWord github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/samples/Sample_26_Html.php)

Comment: In a table cell: `$cell = $table->addCell(6000); \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($cell, $html);`

Comment: Does this support styles !!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer of @Tomek, but you have more html tags possible.

The full list is here :
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/4a530d1d97b064b87d9e2a1cc64cab996246569c/src/PhpWord/Shared/Html.php#L116

Don't try to do complicated thinks with table or style. It just doesn't work.