# Add Text, Html, Embed Image To PHPWord

Tags: php, html

I am using [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) for generating word document using PHP. Actually I need to add content in the below format:

```
Title
Description

Image1
Image1 Description(HTML CONTENT)

Image2 
Image2 Description(HTML CONTENT)
```

So actually I am adding a section and `->addText()/->addImage()` for this.. but in section how can i add `->addHtml()` instead of `->addText()`

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using the example in the repository: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/samples/Sample_26_Html.php

```
 ....
 $section = $phpWord->addSection();
 $html = '<h1>The Description</h1><p>Some description here!';
 \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $html);
 ....
```

But as said in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005670/how-to-convert-the-html-tag-string-to-a-word-document-using-phpword) you can only use tags like `<p>,<h1>,<h2>,<h3>,<h4>,<h5>,<h6>,<strong>,<em>,<sup>,<sub>,<table>,<tr>,<td>,<ul>,<ol>,<li>`

Comment: I already saw this.. But its not exact what i want. we cannot add image and after text to this...